# Greek to ShareLaTeX and moderncv

Tags: greek, sharelatex

I tried to use the ShareLaTeX for my resume using `monderncv` but the tried and could not write Greek. There is a solution, someone has managed to load the Greek in this program?

Comment: How do you compile? Do you use XeLaTeX? Can you add a small example what you are  trying?

Comment: Have a look here.
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52906d353d7d1ee531000e77

Comment: First thing when using XeLaTeX is removing calls to `inputenc`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

As Marco Daniel mentioned, configure XeLaTeX in Settings>Compiler of sharelatex.

To use XeLaTeX, as egreg states, remove:

```
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And then add:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
```

Your document then should look like this, which displays greek properly: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52e6de976f94a9d318000b23